# mysql to mariadb import not working (Syntax Error)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I try to dump a mysql database and import it into my local mariadb server.
What i do is:

```
mysqldump -u db_usr -p -h db.servers.org db_name > db_name.sql
```

and then

```
mysql -u db_usr -p < db_name.sql
```

getting this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4171: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`price`,'$.taxStatus'))) VIRTU...' at line 19
```

My local environment:

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.9-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

mysqldump -V
mysqldump  Ver 10.19 Distrib 10.5.9-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
```

On the remote side there is a mysql server running:

```
mysql -u db_usr -p -h db.servers.org
[...]
Server version: 5.7.29 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
[...]
```

Now i'm wondering:

- If i use my local mysqldump (mariadb-dump) to dump the db, should it not make the dump compatible with my local mariadb installation?
- Are there any means to convert/make compatible the dumps from mysql to mariadb and vice versa?

As i never run into this kind of problem, i'm afraid that in the future such problems will occur more frequently as mariadb and mysql are diverging further. How are we going to handle say eg. hosting migration if the origin is an old mysql server and on the new environment we want to use mariadb?

Comment: mysql -u db_usr -p > db_name.sql. you should use < for import not >.

Comment: @AliMomeni sorry i did use < ;) was a typo, updated the question

Comment: Experience has shown me that table, procedure, and trigger creation in MariaDB is *just different enough* to fail. Whenever I need to migrate from MySQL to MariaDB, I create the tables, procedures, and triggers myself and leave the import to data insertion only. This usually works (for me).

Comment: in your case the syntax to create **virtual fields** is different between MySQL and MariaDB

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Although not what i was hoping for ;) As i have used MariaDB as a drop in replacement for mysql i guess i will have to have both systems in place for testing, if i need to import the one or the other.